# How to pull numeric only values from an array of objects to be added together. An Invoice Generator problem

Tags: javascript

I am new to JavaScript and would like some help with the following problem. How do I access "numbers" only in the array that is holding object values and sum them?

The code for this question is closer to the bottom, the rest is my process and what works so far:

I have an empty array:

```
let customInvoiceItm = []
```

A function then generates the needed HTML and renders items from input fields to the DOM:

```
// RENDER HTML FROM BOTH INPUTS DESCRIPTION AND COST AND DISPALY VIA invoiceItemsArea.innerHTML

function addCustomItem(renderItems) {
    let customItem = ""
    for(let i = 0; i < customInvoiceItm.length; i++){
        customItem += `
        <div class="invoice-task-total">
        <h3 id="inv-task" class="item">${renderItems[i].service}</h3>
        <a href="" id="remove-btn">remove</a>
        <h3 id="inv-total" class="item">$ ${renderItems[i].cost}</h3>
        </div>
        `
    }

    // Outputs the input from the input forms onto the screen
    invoiceItemsArea.innerHTML = customItem
}
```

The above function is triggered by a button and the data from the input fields is stored/sorted into an Object to be placed into the array. Describing an invoice item/service and its cost:

```
// listens for button click and pushes a value from the user entered values from input fields "invoiceDescr" and "invoiceNmbr" Custom Invoice Item Description and Cost into the invoiceArr array
addNewItemBtn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if(invoiceDescr.value === "" && invoiceNmbr.value === "") return 
    
     // Object that sorts input values into its own category
    let items = 
    {
        service:invoiceDescr.value,
        cost:invoiceNmbr.value
    }

    customInvoiceItm.push(items)

    // Clears the Custom Invoice Item and Cost value fields
    console.log(customInvoiceItm)
    
    invoiceDescr.value = ""
    invoiceNmbr.value = ""
    // Saves these values into Browser's local storage
    localStorage.setItem("customInvoiceItm", JSON.stringify(customInvoiceItm))
    
    addCustomItem(customInvoiceItm)
})
```

AND HERE IS WHERE MY QUESTION COMES IN. I am trying to then pull only the numeric values from an array and sum them up and display in the Total Amount field in the DOM by referencing the original array declared at the very top and by using dot notation to access the cost values in all the object numeric values in this array like this:

```
let arrayItems = customInvoiceItm.cost
let sum = arrayItems.reduce((x,y) => x+y)

console.log(sum)
totalAmount.innerText = sum
```

It doesn't work. I get the: `Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "reduce", arrayItems is undefined`

Comment: Please try: `let sum = customInvoiceItem.reduce((x, {cost}) => x+cost, 0);`. The **error** explains that "arrayItems" is "undefined" (& hence, there is no prop named "reduce"). The "arrayItems" is undefined because "customInvoiceItm" does not have any prop named "cost". This is because, "customInvoiceItm" is an array which may have zero or more element/s and may be those element/s may have the prop "cost".

Comment: it works as in it now displays to the DOM, but the values are not added to a total, instead rendered one next to the other as in a list with zero preceding the other numbers

Comment: Instead of `x+cost`, try `x + +cost`

Comment: @jsN00b thank you! Can you please explain the thinking and why behind this? I'd like to understand to be able to use this again if possible?

Comment: I haven't learned the arrow functions yet, how would you write the same code in the ES5 notation, maybe I can grasp it better this way? Thanks!

Comment: Will post an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The objective is to calculate the sum of all `cost`-s which are stored in an array (of objects) named `customInvoiceItm`.

**OP's attempted code is:**

```
let arrayItems = customInvoiceItm.cost
let sum = arrayItems.reduce((x,y) => x+y)

console.log(sum)
totalAmount.innerText = sum
```

**Issues observed in this code are:**

- The variable `customInvoiceItm` is an `Array` (of `object`s)
- So, the reference `customInvoiceItm.cost` may not be the best-fit
- Consequently, `arrayItems` may not have been assigned an intended value
- Which then leads to: `Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "reduce", arrayItems is undefined`
- The error explicitly indicates that the `"reduce"` prop can't be accessed in `arrayItems`

**How to circumvent / resolve:**

- Since `customInvoiceItm` is an array of objects (& from other relevant code, it is deduced that the objects in this array have a prop named `cost`), one may completely avoid using a variable such as `arrayItems`
- One needs to iterate through the `customInvoiceItm` and access the `cost` prop of each & every object
- Then, accumulate (ie, sum) these `cost`s
- Based on further feedback (from OP, in comments), it was understood that `cost` is being treated as a `string` and not a `number`
- Adding a `+` prefix to `cost` solves that issue

**The updated solution:**

```
let sum = customInvoiceItm.reduce(
  (x, {cost}) => x+ +cost,
  0
);
```

**Why this solution works:**

- The `.reduce()` iterates over the `customInvoiceItm` array
- The parameters for the arrow-function (in `reduce`) are `x` (which is the accumulator / aggregator) and the current-iteration / object of the array.
- By using `{cost}` one is able to de-structure the current-iteration / object and directly access the prop `cost`
- The arrow-function does an implicit return by not having curly braces & `return` explicitly.
- It returns the value `x + +cost` for each iteration
- The `+cost` transforms (immutably) the `string` value of `cost` into a number
- The `, 0` following the implicit return notifies that the initial value for `x` (the aggregator) is `0`

**The solution without arrow-function:**

```
let sum = customInvoiceItm
  .reduce(
    function(x, {cost}){
      return (x+ +cost);
    },
    0
  );
```

The above should get the same result as before.

One may even choose to not de-structure, and not to use `+` prefix, to try something like so:

```
let sum = customInvoiceItm
  .reduce(
    function(x, item){
      return ( x + Number(item.cost));
    },
    0
  );
```

NOTE: Typically, one avoids posting such answers as these discuss extremely fundamental concepts that are much better-explained in other sources (tutorials, etc). This answer may please be deleted based on community-members feedback (from comments, if any).